# POST and GET methods

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, html

I want to transfer a data from one webpage to another page. But I don't want to use the `<form method="post">` tag because there are no forms in my webpage. Just some sensitive data is there which needs to be transferred to other page.

Please answer the following questions:

1. What are the ways to transfer data from one page to another?
2. What are the ways to transfer data from one page to another without using `<form>` tag in HTML?
3. How can another PHP (or ASP) page can read the data which was sent to it by another page?

Comment: will $.post([myData]) w/ or w/o ajax solve your problem? (jquery)

Comment: @Ismael: I think it will solve my problem. But for that I will need to trigger the javascript function which will send the data. But in my webpage, after querying the data from database I want to send it to the next webpage.

Comment: Given that the data is "sensitive" (which is a subjective term), maybe it should be kept server-side and transferred via session/database/etc.?

Comment: David - the data is being generated by the user of the website.

Comment: @iSumitG i see no easy way without triggering something or doing some plugin tweak. Anyway, there is no "perfect way" doing this. Doing an invisible <form> is not a sin and no one will fire you away. This is how the HTML worlds works anyway..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't want to use the `<form method="post">` tag because there are no forms in my webpage

That is not a good reason to avoid using a form. You can add one.

> What are the ways to transfer data from one page to another?

1. Through the URI (in a query string)
2. As part of the request body (a POST request)
3. Via cookies (which you can set with JS)
4. Via various [local storage systems](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Use a query string if the data needs to be bookmarkable. Use a POST request (with a form) if it makes changes on the server (e.g. adds or edits a database entry). Use a cookie (preferably set via HTTP after using methods 1 or 2) if the data needs to persist throughout the site. Use local storage for web applications that need to function offline.

> What are the ways to transfer data from one page to another without using  tag in HTML?

As above, but discount post requests (unless you make them using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest).

> How can another PHP (or ASP) page can read the data which was sent to it by another page?

With local storage, it can't. All the other data is available through the server environment (`$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` in PHP, for example).

Comment: Cookies cannot be shared between different domains though correct?

Comment: @iSumitG — Under some limited circumstances it will, but they shouldn't be relied upon. There is nothing wrong with submit buttons, and you can style them (although making them look like they aren't buttons isn't a very good idea).

Comment: @NeilMonday — correct, but cross domain wasn't a stated requirement.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for the help. I am taking payment information from user. Sending the data to another PHP page using `POST` method. This PHP page will insert the data into database (like order_details, shipping address etc) and will generate an `order_id` and then it will redirect to another page (say order confirmation page) which will show that the message "Order confirmed. Your order id is: 1234". Now my problem is that how to transfer the order_id from PHP page to order confirmation page. Since PHP is kind of an intermediate processing page, there are no `<form>` in it.

Comment: The query string would be the sensible place to put it (set it in the Location header when you do an HTTP redirect). Just make sure that the conformation page checks that the order id belongs to the customer making the order.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use a hidden input i.e. `<input name="secret" type="hidden" value="superSecretData" />`
2. You could create a random element which contains the data i.e. `<div style="display: none">SuperSecretData</div>`

3a. In the case of the former in php it would just be a matter of accessing `$_POST['secret']`

3b. In the case of the later you would need to use javascript of something of that sort to take the random element and send it along with the page.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1.) [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) if available, hash tags, or flash

2.) same as 1

3.) again you can use EasyXDM

if you open the other page with window.open or similar, or iframes